# Trigger on slave only

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I am trying to run a trigger on slave for RBR (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/running-triggers-on-the-slave-for-row-based-events/).
I have created a table on master like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mobile` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

On slave, I had this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1_obfus AFTER INSERT ON `t1`
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE `t1`
SET `mobile` = LEFT(MD5(NEW.`mobile`), 20);
```

which did not work. I got the following error on `SHOW SLAVE STATUS`:

> Last_SQL_Error: Could not execute Write_rows_v1 event on table d1.t1; Can't update table 't1' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger., Error_code: 1442; handler error HA_ERR_GENERIC; the event's master log mariadb-bin.000004, end_log_pos 454

Then I modified the trigger to:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1_obfus BEFORE INSERT ON `t1`
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE `t1`
SET NEW.`mobile` = LEFT(MD5(NEW.`mobile`), 20)
WHERE id = NEW.id;
```

but it still did not work. Then I created a new table on slave:

```
CREATE TABLE t1_2 (
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    mobile VARCHAR(20)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and modified my trigger to:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1_obfus BEFORE INSERT ON `t1_2`
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO `t1_2` (id, mobile)
VALUES (NEW.id,LEFT(MD5(NEW.`mobile`), 20));
```

Now the replication started working but there is no data in the table `t1_2`. How do I fix this?

Comment: The first pair doesn't work on the reason which is explained in the error message itself, regardless whether it's a slave-only trigger or not: the trigger can't update the table for which it was invoked. What are you trying to achieve by the second pair of table/trigger? Naturally it won't affect replication, because the new trigger has nothing to do with it. Since you created `t1_2` only on slave, it means you are not inserting into it on master, hence such inserts are not replicated and the trigger is not used. If you try to insert into `t1_2` on slave, you'll get the same error as before.

Comment: Please make some minimal effort to format code to be readable by others before posting next time.

Comment: @underscore_d Sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you use row-based replication, triggers on the slave won't work.
As described in the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-features-triggers.html):

> Blockquote
>   If you want triggers to execute on both the master and the slave—perhaps because you have different triggers on the master and slave—you must use statement-based replication. However, to enable slave-side triggers, it is not necessary to use statement-based replication exclusively. It is sufficient to switch to statement-based replication only for those statements where you want this effect, and to use row-based replication the rest of the time.

Comment: I was using MariaDB. The documentation you provided is for MySQL. Also, the see the link to the RBR article in my question.